# Converting Node.js HMAC to C++

Tags: c++, node.js, hmac, crypto++

Ive been working on a project, and as part of it I need to convert the Node.js code

```
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', key).update(text).digest('hex');
```

to C++. I've decided to use Crypto++, leading to the following code:

```
//Creating the key from an integer instead of a string or byte array
char bytes[sizeof key];
std::copy(static_cast<const char*>(static_cast<const void*>(&key)),
    static_cast<const char*>(static_cast<const void*>(&key)) + sizeof key,
    bytes);
SecByteBlock key(bytes, sizeof(bytes));

//Create HMAC using server seed as key and client seed as message
HMAC< SHA512 > hmac(key, key.size());
string plain = "HMAC Test";
string mac, encoded;

StringSource ss2(text, true, new HashFilter(hmac, new StringSink(mac)) /* HashFilter*/);
```

Are these two code blocks equivalent? I'm much more familiar with JS so I'm not certain the C++ code is entirely correct in function.

Comment: Run them using test vectors, like [RFC 4231, Identifiers and Test Vectors for HMAC-SHA-224, HMAC-SHA-256, HMAC-SHA-384, and HMAC-SHA-512](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4231). If the results are different, then Node.js likely uses an encoding like UTF-16 rather than the string of bytes.

Comment: If you provide production code, then I can tell you more about the use in Crypto++. As it stands, `char bytes[sizeof key];` and then later `SecByteBlock key(bytes, sizeof(bytes));` won't compile. The use of `sizeof key` could be wrong, too, if its a pointer. Also see [HMAC](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HMAC) on the Crypto++ wiki.